# How to include UserDir paths to ProxyPass - Apache 2.4.7 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apache, ubuntu, proxypass, mod-userdir

I have this configuration:

Ubuntu Server 14.04

> Apache 2.4.7 with proxy_module
>
> PHP 5.5.9 + PHP5-FPM

I am passing all request for PHP files, with the php file extension, to the PHP wrapper through FastCGI with the following command:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/html/$1
```

Now the problem is that when I am accessing the server with the following URL `http://127.0.0.1/~myuser/phpinfo.php` I receive **File not found**

If I am accessing it like this `http://127.0.0.1/phpinfo.php` it's working.

My question is how can I get rid of **File not found** error when I want to access the url with the user in it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add following lines to your httpd configuration

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/~myuser/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/path/to/myuser/public_html/$1
```